# File sorting order in Textmate project drawer

Tags: textmate

Is it possible to change the file sorting order in Textmate's project drawer, say, from `by name` to `by kind`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it isn't supported natively in TextMate, the [ProjectPlus](http://ciaranwal.sh/2008/08/05/textmate-plug-in-projectplus) plugin lets you sort folders on top, and sort files by type.